# How is screen orientation determined for nosensor settings in Android?

Tags: android

How is screen orientation determined for "nosensor" screen orientation mode in Android? When is it going to be portrait vs landscape?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
    // In landscape
} else {
    // In portrait
}
```